# Understanding the lifecycle of Vue Instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm going through the official documentation of Vue.js and found [this diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) about different stages and steps in a Vue instance's lifecycle. I understand the basic features of Vue but I am unable to understand the meaning of many stages mentioned in the diagram. For example, "Compile template into render function" or "Virtual DOM re-render and patch". I have no idea what they mean.

I know it says in the documentation that you don’t need to fully understand everything right now, but I was hoping if some Vue(or frontend) expert could briefly explain these steps in simple language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can all be a little overwhelming, here's what those things are

**Render Functions**

When Vue compiles your Vue instance, it creates a `render function`, which is a pure JavaScript representation of your HTML. Something like this:

```
new Vue({
  template: `<div>{{msg}}</div>`,
  data:{
    msg: 'Hello Vue
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Will actually turn into something like this:

```
new Vue({
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', this.msg)
  },
  data: {
    msg: 'Hello Vue'
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bvvbmpLo/

You don't need to handle that, Vue does it for you, and most of the time you won't find yourself writing render functions. However, it is important to understand that Vue is doing some behind the scenes work to represent your templates in pure JavaScript.

**Virtual DOM re-render and patch**

You really don't need to know about this, but Vue uses a virtual DOM, because it's is easier to track changes and decide which parts of the DOM need updating.

In reality, what happens is that Vue builds up a tree that represents the DOM (called a `vTree`), then when you change state it uses something called a `diffing` algorithm which compares the previous `vTree` to the current `vTree` as it now stands, and attempts to figure out which part of the page it needs to change to reflect that state in your view. The changing of a small part of your page to represent the new state is called `patching`.

That's a pretty high-level overview of a virtual DOM, it's fiendishly complex to get this working efficiently which is why frameworks like Vue exist in the first place. If you're interested in learning more about that then try taking a look at [Matt-Esch/virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom) on Github, which does a great job of explaining this concept in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! Could you please include some explanation about one more step of the lifecycle - “Create vm.$el and replace el with it”.